# Is this the proper flow of client-server communication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am building my first full stack application. I have two seperate apps, a client app built with create-react-app and a node express server to serve json.

Currently, my create-react-app which uses Redux, makes ajax calls using axios to the port that my server is running on. I have set up authentication for the server to exchange a token with my client upon success.

My goal is to make use of the Spotify API. For their authentication, it says I need to get a authentication token from their server via my server.

I am not sure the proper way to go about this.

Currently my thought process is to have my client hit a new route in my server via a axios ajax call to have my server asynchronously exchange the token with the spotify api and then send it back to the client.. is this the proper way?

I've seen various other examples of this being done but they have their node/express app manage the routes for their entire application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: I don't really follow what you're trying to do, but keep in mind that ANYTHING you send to the client is insecure (you mention sending auth tokens to the client) and can be accessed by anyone.

Comment: If spotify api is used directly from the client, then bypass the server and directly deal with spotify. Does spotify allow third party apps like yours to connect from the backend? If so, and if that is what is required, connect to spotify at the server.